Android Apollo Client cannot create http cache
I'm trying to set up an http cache in my Android app. I have the following code:
val file = File("apolloCache")

ApolloClient.Builder().httpCache(
    directory = file,
    maxSize = (100 * 1024 * 1024).toLong()
)

The file object is created successfully. But when I run the second line, the app crashes with this error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokio/FileSystem;
at com.apollographql.apollo3.cache.http.HttpCache.configureApolloClientBuilder(HttpCacheExtensions.kt:77)

What am I missing here?

Feels like you are missing the Okio dependency or you are getting a version that differs from what Apollo expects.
